# How to handle a wrong answer in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a program where input my first name into the `textbox` and if it's correct the label text changes from "First Name" to "Last Name" and the button text changes from "Check to "Enter".
 If I put in an answer that isn't my name into the `textbox` then the label is supposed to change to "Incorrect re-enter". I have the first part down for putting in my first name correctly:

```
If TxtBox.Text = "justin" Then
        Lbl.Text = "Last Name"
        Btn.Text = "Enter"
    ElseIf TxtBox.Text = "Justin" Then
        Lbl.Text = "Last Name"
        Btn.Text = "Enter"
    End If
```

But I can't figure out how to set up a reaction to a wrong answer. 
Afterwards i'm supposed to enter my last name in the text field and when I click the button the text field becomes read only and the button's label becomes "correct", if the last name in the text field is wrong the button's label should become "incorrect try again" and everything else stays the same. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to use a `while(True)` loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in the method handling textbox text changes:

```
If Lbl.Text = "First Name" Then   
    If TxtBox.Text = "justin" Or TxtBox.Text = "Justin" Then
        Lbl.Text = "Last Name"
        Btn.Text = "Enter"
    Else
        Lbl.Text = "Incorrect. Re-enter."
    End If
Else
    If TxtBox.Text <> "your last name" Then
        Lbl.Text = "Incorrect. Re-enter."
    Else
        Lbl.Text = "Correct."
    End If
End If
```

In the method handling the button:

```
If Lbl.Text = "Correct" Then
    Btn.Text = "Correct"
    TxtBox.Enabled = False
Else
    Btn.Text = "Incorrect. Try again."
End IF
```